# Bootstrap modal backkdrop glitches on tablet rotation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap modal for an web app designed mainly for tablets. When opening the modal in either portrait or landscape mode, the display is ok. However, if I open the modal in one of the modes and then rotate the table to the other, all visual effects respond ok, apart from the backdrop, and because of it, the modal dialog is out of position too:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this or workaround?